# How can I disable the keyboard shortcuts in Zoom on Microsoft Windows?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, zoom-meeting

How can I disable the keyboard shortcuts in Zoom on Microsoft Windows?

For example the keyboard shortcut for muting/unmuting  the microphone is  <kbd>SPACE</kbd>: I would like to disable it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For muting and unmuting using Space, go to Settings > Audio, disable "Press and hold SPACE key to temporarily unmute yourself".

For other shortcuts, go to Settings > Keyboard shortcuts.

And to access Settings, you'll need to be logged in to Zoom.

---

[image]

Comment: "And to access Settings, you'll need to be logged in to Zoom." ahhh that's what I was missing. Good way to force people to log in. Thanks  for the information!